# Glide not downloading images from a redirect link

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to download a image using glide but it gives me the below when the image comes from a redirect link.

Here's my code

```
Glide.with(this.context).load(url).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Does anyone have any idea?

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-apps/imrs.php?src=https://arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/63EVGHLOZFDZJFRRUDUUVY65NY.jpg&w=1440 with size [275x275]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(In re-direct loop)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(In re-direct loop)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(In re-direct loop)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: In re-direct loop
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: In re-direct loop
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:79)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:118)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:56)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been classified as a BUG.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/4652